# SQL developer unit testing bug?

Tags: unit-testing, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have decided to start using unit testing in PL/SQL, since it could be fun and improve the quality of the code.

So, Ive read several resources available and picked SQL Developer and its unit testing capabilities.

I ran into a stupid problem, and Google failed me.

I'm unit testing a simple package.

```
--Package spec
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE SAMPLE_TEST
AS

TYPE SAMPLE_RECORD
IS
  RECORD
  (
    SAMPLE_NUMBER NUMBER(3),
    SAMPLE_DATE DATE,
    SAMPLE_INTEGER INTEGER );

PROCEDURE DO_SOMETHING(
    P_FILE VARCHAR2,
    P_RESULT OUT SAMPLE_RECORD);
--OR FUNCTION (..) RETURN SAMPLE_RECORD...    

END SAMPLE_TEST;
```

With the implementation:

```
--Package body
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY SAMPLE_TEST
AS
PROCEDURE SAMPLE_PROC(
    P_FILE VARCHAR2,
    P_RESULT OUT SAMPLE_RECORD)
AS
BEGIN
  P_RESULT.SAMPLE_NUMBER    := SUBSTR(P_FILE, 0 ,3);
  P_RESULT.SAMPLE_DATE      := TO_DATE(SUBSTR(P_FILE, 4 ,8), 'DD.MM.RRRR');
  P_RESULT.SAMPLE_INTEGER   := SUBSTR(P_FILE, 20);
END SAMPLE_PROC;
END SAMPLE_TEST;
```

The input string is **035200220122102201213**.

The result is - an ERROR. Assertion failed.
The procedure is correct, it returns the correct values, but the "unit testing framework" informs me:

```
P_RESULT : Expected: [<SAMPLE_NUMBER=35, SAMPLE_DATE=20.02.12, SAMPLE_INTEGER=13>], 
           Received: [<SAMPLE_NUMBER=35, SAMPLE_DATE=20.02.12, SAMPLE_INTEGER=13>]
```

I can't find a submited bug anywhere - metalink, Google - any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this page https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2382730
says there is a problem with ref cursors and unit testing...

maybe its related.

Comment: I don't think that link has any similarities to my example. I don't have a ref cursor, and I certanly didn't exceed 2000 bytes. But, since no one is answering this question, you get a gold star for the effort :)